Backup github and restore when github down
I need to backup github repo  and restore it to another git server (eg: gitlab/bitbucket etc, with all those issue/pull request/tag/branches restore)
Assumption:

The backup will not be sync to another repo. It will only be restore to another git repo when github is down
During restore time to another git server, GITHUB service is completely down and not accessible.
Not depending on any other paid backup solution service

I am currently using git clone --bare to do backup but I am unsure if it is dependent on GITHUB service availability when restoring to gitlab/bitbucket etc
Or if there is a better way to do backup (Eg: git clone --mirror, git bundle)

git clone --bare needs to be able to connect to the git server you are cloning from, just as git clone or git fetch with other arguments. Note that you cannot use git commands for replicating issues or pull requests.

^ this is because issues and pull requests are not a part of Git itself, but instead a feature of whichever repository hosting service or software you use. Tags and branches should be included in git clone --mirror, but that command only works if your remote (GitHub, etc.) is available.
